# SearchView: Set the background color and also the icon of the action button using a SearchView

Tags: java, android, searchview

Can anyone help me with this? I am working with a SearchView in order to look for places of a list. I would like to change the background color and also the icon of the action button of the soft keyboard. Keep in mind that the SearchView is not in the toolbar.

This is my code:

XML:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/AppSearchView"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"
    android:inputType="text"
    app:queryHint="Search something..."/>
```

[image: Check the image about what I want to change]

Comment: Add your implemented or tried source code with the question. Then other will be modify or show what your are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` to change the background color of your searchView.
2. And to change your keyboard icon you can use `android:imeOptions` on your editText TAG.

eg:

```
<EditText
android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
android:inputType="text" />
```

You can find more options in the [android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style) site.

Comment: Thanks KalanaChinthaka. The thing is that the view I am using is not an EditText, it is a SearchView. What shall I put in the xml file under the tag "SearchView?

Comment: You can use android:imeOptions="actionSearch"  in your searchView as well.